# Arrayformula Vlookup to return multiple values with one search_key

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

[image]I am trying to get the below formula to provide me the values from column A that have the matching program key found in the AF column. I'm trying to have ALL the values that match show up, and not just one.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(dts_program_key,{'CMT Upload'!AF2:AF,'CMT Upload'!A2:A},2,0))`

`dts_program_key = 926d4c81-cf34-4299-abcc-23ba22a6dbe9`

The "CMT Upload" tab that the data is being pulled from:

| Contract Lane Key (Column A) | Program Key (Column AF) |
| --- | --- |
| TestA | 13d9c80a-0a09-4e84-8157-94a40c04d1fe |
| :---- | :------: |
| TestB | 926d4c81-cf34-4299-abcc-23ba22a6dbe9 |
| :---- | :------: |
| TestC | 0e2183bc-d2ee-4835-836c-b117024b6d09 |
| :---- | :------: |
| TestD | 926d4c81-cf34-4299-abcc-23ba22a6dbe9 |
| :---- | :------: |
| TestE | 926d4c81-cf34-4299-abcc-23ba22a6dbe9 |

In the above example, the vlookup should provide TestB, TestD, and TestE, all without any empty rows in between. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP is designed to only return the first match. If you want to return all the matches, use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) instead.

```
=FILTER('CMT Upload'!A2:A,'CMT Upload'!AF2:AF=dts_program_key)
```